# How to prepare for reading Blau‘s lecture notes about general relativity from scratch？

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, education

I'm a student majoring in computer science, which means that I haven't learned any physics related courses. Furthermore, I only know calculus (at the level of introductory real analysis, well, the first half of baby Rudin, as well as informal multivariable calculus), linear algebra (not rigorous version, and absolutely nothing about multi-linear algebra), probability and statistics (also not rigorous - not based on measure theory). However, I have an interest in knowing things about relativity theory, so I decided to study related knowledge on my own. I find Blau's lecture notes are very good, and since I haven't learnt much about physics, I started to look up the preface of these lecture notes and find that it requires knowledge about: lagranian mechanics, rigorous special relativities, vector calculus.

Can anyone recommand some books or lecture notes about these three fields? Or can any one recommand some rooadmap for me to learn general relativity theory to the level that I can read Blau's lecture note without lacking related knowledge? (and I find the part of rigorous special relativity is very difficult for me to find any related materials)

Comment: I think that Blau's notes are some of the best material out there regarding both mathematics and physical intuition. In my opinion the books of Leonard Susskind "Classical mechanics" And "special relativity and classical field theory " are sufficient to understand Blau.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resource recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/168783)